# Is there any way to detect on a website if the mouse has not been moved for awhile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an element to appear in case the website has not been used for a while and make it disappear after it is being used again. Is there any way to detect on a website if the mouse has not been moved for awhile?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Ok sorry guys, I will ask better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an event handler that takes mouse position whenever mouse is moved store it in variable and store the exact time that happened.

Make a timer that runs each lets say each minute and checks if the last stored mouse position and time is older than a minute then make that element you want to appear
else make sure the hide that element.

Comment: This is simple enough, and it'll work. You don't really have to store the exact time, you can just increment a flag every `x` seconds: [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Comment: It worked great. I used @YannisRizos link if anyone else needs this.

Comment: What about touch devices?  What about people using the keyboard to navigate the page?  Sure, you've detected the mouse movements but what about the bigger issue?

Comment: Good point @SeanMcSomething . My website has a really specific use case so I only need the mouse but would be interesting to hear solutions for keyboard, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can set up a timer that expires after the desired amount of time of mouse inactivity, and reinitialize it whenever the mouse is moved.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472705/resetting-a-settimeout) for an example (`clearTimeout` followed by `setTimeout`).